# Decode a regex to know if it allows numbers only

Tags: regex, swift

I receive a regex as a string. Is it possible to know if the regex only permits number ?
The regex I receive are mainly of the form :

- ^[0-9]+$
- ^[0-9]{5,10}$
- ^[0-9]{6}$
- ^[0-9]{1,13}\w$

But I may receive other regex.

Comment: Well, if it contains anything other than [0-9], \d, +, *, $, ^ , {, }, commas inside the curly brackets or numbers, then it accepts something else too. Also,  \+, \*, etc. doesn't count

Comment: You would need to parse the whole regex to see if it allows matching more than digits. `[0-9]` and `\w` and `\d` and `\p{N...}` will match digits. And a more difficult case is when the digit range is hidden inside another, like [`[.-:]`](https://regex101.com/r/vAI6if/1).

Comment: If you have doubts about what the regex does, just copy&paste it in one of the online regex solvers. For example [here](https://regex101.com/) or [here](http://www.regexr.com/). And then look at the Explain. For those 4 examples, only the last one allows more than digits.

Comment: @LukStorms He has to do it with code

Comment: @Bálint Oh, code to check what a regex does? Huh, that's a first. O_o

Comment: @LukStorms Technically regey parsers do that

Comment: @Bálint. Yes I have to do it in code. The idea is to select the right keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most people have pointed, this is a particularly complex task to achieve using a simple regex, since there are a lot of ways in which the same thing can be written, including cases where digits are hidden inside character classes, or negated character classes etc. Nonetheless, I gave it a shot and tested it out a bit, it works for basic scenarios.

**The below regex matches *any regex that matches only digits*, and not any other characters.** It may allow one or more digits, restrict only particular digits etc. which doesn't really matter. The capturing regex only ensures that the matched regex **doesn't match any non-numbers**.

- The regex matches various ways of representing digits including `\d`, `[0-9]`, `\p{N}`, `[123]` and even literals `4` but not negated character classes `[^\WA-Za-z_]` or `[.-:]`
- The regex matches a regex with or without anchor tags
- The regex includes support for all quantifiers, including `*`, `+`, `?` and even `{x,y}`. Also works with non-greedy and possessive quantifiers i.e `\d*?` and `\d*+`
- The regex works with positive or negative lookbehinds and lookaheads both.
- The regex includes support for `|` such as `\d?|[34]?|123`

**Limitations:**

- The regex doesn't support capturing or non-capturing groups since that makes it quite complex. So any regex containing `(..)` capturing group or `(:..)` non-capturing group will fail even though they might by digit only
- The regex doesn't support negated character classes. For example: `[^\WA-Za-z_]` matches only digits, but it won't work.
- Though this isn't exactly a limitation, but wanted to point out that validation of the regex is NOT done.

Regex:

```
^\^?((\(\?\<[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?(\[\d*(?:\d-\d)?\d*\]|\\d|\\p\{N\}|\d+(?:\|\d+)*)(\*|\+|\?|\{\d*,?\d*\})?(\?|\+)?(\(\?[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?)+(?:\|(?:(?:\(\?\<[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?(\[\d*(\d-\d)?\d*\]|\\d|\\p\{N\}|\d+(\|\d+)*)(\*|\+|\?|\{\d*,?\d*\})?(\?|\+)?(\(\?[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?))*\$?$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T6Pghm/9/)

An easier way to visualise the solution is:

```
^(lookbehind)?(digit_classes)+(quantifier)?(quantifier_type)?(lookahead)?

lookbehind = (?<=.. or (?<!..
digit_classes = \d or [0-9] or \p{N} etc.
quantifier = * or + or ? or {,}
quantifier_type = ? or +
lookahead = (?=.. or (?!..

// Repeat the above to support 'OR' i.e |
```

`((\(\?\<[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?(\[\d*(?:\d-\d)?\d*\]|\\d|\\p\{N\}|\d+(?:\|\d+)*)(\*|\+|\?|\{\d*,?\d*\})?(\?|\+)?(\(\?[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?)+` or the first capturing group includes support for all types of digits described in detail below.

1. First capturing group `(\(\?\<[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?` includes matching **positive or negative look behinds**

   - `\(\?\<` includes the start of a look behind i.e `(?<` followed by `[=!]` since it could be positive or negative
   - `[^\(\)]*?` non-greedily allows any character other than `(` or `)` to be present in the lookbehind
2. Next capturing group `(\[\d*(?:\d-\d)?\d*\]|\\d|\\p\{N\}|\d+(?:\|\d+)*)` includes matching **various digit representations** such as `\d` or `[0-9]` or `\p{N}`

   - `[\d*(?:\d-\d)?\d*\]` matches `[0-9]` or `[1234]` or even `[1-3567]`
   - `\\d` matches `\d` directly
   - `\\p\{N\}` matches `\p{N}` directly
   - `\d+(?:\|\d+)*` allows literals to be present eg. '4' and support multiple literals too, such as `4|6|8`
3. Next capturing group `(\*|\+|\?|\{\d*,?\d*\})?` includes matching all **quantifiers** i.e `*`, `+`, `?`, `{,}`.

   - `\*|\+|\?` represents all the basic quantifiers
   - `\{\d*,?\d*\}` supports quantifiers specifying minimum and maximum counts such as `\d{5,}` or `[0-9]{3,6}` etc.
4. Next capturing group `(\?|\+)?` allows support for marking **type of quantifier**, such as lazy i.e `\d*?` or possessive i.e `\d*+`
5. Next capturing group `(\(\?[=!][^\(\)]*?\))?` allows **positive or negative lookaheads**

After this the first capturing group is repeated once more to support using `|` between multiple digit representations i.e say the above groups are represented by `(..)*` so to include support for `|`, it is duplicated likes this `(..)+(\|(..))*` to come up with the final regex.

Works for:

```
^[0-9]{6}$
^[0-9]+$
^[0-9]{5,10}$
\d[0][3-9]*?\d[0-7]*?$
\d*|[0-9]+|123
\d+(?!\s)
(?<=\w)[0-9]
```

Doesn't work for (but should work):

```
(\d)*          # Capturing groups don't work
(?:\d+)        # Non-capturing groups don't work
^[^\WA-Za-z_]  # Negated character classes don't work
```

***Note:** All groups are capturing groups so that visualising them is easier. They can all be converted to non-capturing anytime.*

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d|(?<!\^)\d-\d|\\d|\^|\$|\[|\]|{\d+(,\d+)?}|\+|\*|\\b|\\B|\\\d|\(\?[:=!<][^]+\)|\?|\||\((\d|(?<!\^)\d-\d|\\d|\^|\$|\[|\]|{\d+(,\d+)?}|\+|\*|\\b|\\B|\\\d|\(\?[:=!<][^]+\)|\?|\|)+\))+$
```

I know...I know

This only matches stuff, that could be in a regular expression, that matches digits. This includes `(?=My phone number is: )[\d-]+`, which matches `123-4567-890` in `My phone number is: 123-4567-890`.

To test whether a RegEx only matches digits, try matching it with this. If it matches anything, then it's okay.

This doesn't catch invalid ones, e.g. `\d^\d$\d`

If you notice any errors in it, then please let me know, and I'll correct it.